# without succes i am trying to get 1 object from array in foreach laravel5.4

Tags: laravel

I want show all template in my db but i get this error Trying to get property of non-object. here is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('product_create')}}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <select class="form-control" name="template">
                @foreach($templates as $template =>$key)
                    <option value="{{$key->id}}" {{isset($key)&& $key->id == $$key->name ? 'selected' :'' }} ></option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Product toevoegen">
        </form>
```

If i dd $template i get this array

```
array:2 [▼
1 => "product"
2 => "test"
]
```

Here is the controller

```
   if (isset($_POST['template']) && !empty($_POST['template'])){
        $propertyTemplate = PropertyTemplate::find($_POST['template']);
    }else{
        $propertyTemplate = PropertyTemplate::find(1);
    }
```

what do i do wrong here

Comment: Can you add the code of your controller where you pass `$templates` ?

Comment: @Maraboc hanks for your answer.    if (isset($_POST['template']) && !empty($_POST['template'])){
            $propertyTemplate = PropertyTemplate::find($_POST['template']);
        }else{
            $propertyTemplate = PropertyTemplate::find(1);
        }

Comment: And you pass the `$propertyTemplate` to the view ?? because there will be just one template not an array of templates !!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean!

Comment: can you show `dd($propertyTemplate)` in the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach($templates as $key =>$template)
      <option value="{{$key}}">{{$template}}</option>
 @endforeach
```